# How can i manage multiple method calls as one transaction

Tags: java, api, rest, transactions, transactionscope

I have a problem with establishing a transaction manager/scope for my REST API (JAVA), I have below functions in my API back end and i want to excute all below functions as one transaction,

1. Call third party WS end point
2. Decrypt the response
3. Save the response in to DB1
4. Save the response in to DB2

I want to make sure all above steps are completed or rollback if any one fail, I have enough information to do the rollback, but i have no idea what would be the best practice to implement proper transaction management mechanism, because above mentioned steps happen in 3 separate classes per API call,
This is a pseudo code for my class structure

```
class CallWS {
public People callThWS() {
  // functions related to call third party WS and decryption (step 1,2)
 }
}

class People peopleServices {  
   public People getPeopleData() {
        callThWS ppl= new callThWS();
        People pplObj = ppl.callThWS(); 
        // save to DB1, (step 3)
        return pplObj;
   }
}

class People peopleContr {
 public People getAllPeople() {
    peopleServices ppSer= new peopleServices();
    People pplObj2 =  ppSer.getPeopleData();
    // save to DB2, (Step 4)
    return  pplObj2; 
 }
}
```

Please help me on this,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Distributed Transactions(XA). Check for examples of various transaction managers which support XA. Check [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077714/java-web-development/xa-transactions-using-spring.html) article for using XA provider in standalone applications(Warning: Old article).

Answer (score 0):

If you control sources of all classes listed and you can refactor your code the way you have a single entry point, you can do it quite easily, except the call to an external web service. The pseudo code is below.

Here we should agree that all resources your are calling in your methods are transactional. As I mentioned earlier call to an external WS would not fall to that category because calls to external web services are not transactional by their nature. Again if you do not change data withing a call to the external service you may consider just leave it outside transaction. You still have a bit of control. Like rolling back transaction in case a call to the external service was unsuccessful and as far as you have not changed anything on the other side, you may not care about rolling back a transaction there.

However you still have some options for a transaction call to an external WS call like [Web Services Atomic Transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13734/transaction.htm#WSADV382), but I bet you would need control for sources and maybe even environment on the other side. In such a lucky circumstances you would rather want to achieve it by avoiding the WS call.

```
class RestAPIEntryPointResource {
    @Inject
    CallWS callWS;

    @Inject
    PeopleServices peopleServices ;

    @Inject
    PeopleContr peopleContr;

 /*Put some transaction demarcation here. 
If your class is an EJB, it is already done for you. 
With Spring you have various options to mark the method transactional. 
You also may want to take a manual control, but it look redundant here. */
    public void entryPointMethod() {
        callWS.callThWS();
        peopleServices.getPeopleData();
        peopleContr.getAllPeople();
    }
}

class CallWS {
    public People callThWS() {
        // functions related to call third party WS and decryption (step 1,2)
    }
}

class PeopleServices {
    public People getPeopleData() {
        ..........
    }
}

class PeopleContr {
    public People getAllPeople() {
        .........
    }
}
```